# Possible to have two conditions for an IF statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Alright so I am currently making a PBBG based game. However, I have been having trouble with my function for a button click and two conditions in my if statement. I am actually not positive if this is at all possible, I searched everywhere I could think of but nothing gave me a definitive answer for getting this to work.

Basically, what I am trying to achieve, is that when a player presses the 'Attack' button, the player then receives the amount of experience points and gold they get from defeating that monster. Then, after that function runs, I am setting a delay of 6 seconds to where they can't press the button to attack again until the 6 seconds have passed.

I did get the function and onClick to work where when they win the fight, the game awards them the experience and gold from the kill. That all worked great and I made sure that was all working BEFORE I started adding in the time delay function and all.

Here is my code for the function with the time delay I am trying to add: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNElR.png)
(Won't allow me to embed pictures yet so a link will have to do for now) and I am using just an HTML button with the onClick value set to SingleAttack().  The code with the problem appears to be in this part...

```
if (attackReady) || (currentExp >= NeededExp) {...}
```

What I have done here is I am holding a boolean, named attackReady and setting it to 'true'. When the player presses the Attack button, it then changes the 'true' value to 'false' and then adds a setTimeout() and period in miliseconds for delay. It then sets attackReady back to true and puts a 6 second time delay before the function can be called again.

You'll notice there is an if and an else if in my function. The if code runs only when a players current experience points are greater than or equal to the needed experience points. I think my problem is coming from having two conditions in the if statement. I am not entirely sure if that is possible, I have looked everywhere to find an answer and nothing for javascript specifically. I know C# allows it, does javascript allow it and if so, did I do it right or have I done it wrong?

When the Attack button is clicked and the function is called, it does nothing at all. Any insights?

Comment: `if( myVar > 1 && myVar != 3) return true;`

Comment: That is how you would check two conditions in one if statement. It is checking to make sure that `myVar` is greater than 1 but also that it isn't 3.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Make sure you set the parentheses and curly brackets correctly. Follow the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Comment: Hi, if you want to add your code directly to the post, which is also easier for everyone to read, you can copy and paste it in

Comment: please [*do not post code as imaged*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)! It has a *reason* that you cant embed pictures.

Comment: Rather than `if (attackReady) || (currentExp >= NeededExp) {...}` try `if( attackReady || currentExp >= NeededExp ) {...}`.  Please note that `||` is *OR* while `&&` is *AND*.

Comment: @Thomas Valadez Thanks for that. I was told it was || for two conditions.

Comment: @JonSG With two conditions I thought it was two separate parentheses sets. Thanks for showing me correctly. Also a side question, since || means OR then my code would run if EITHER of the conditions were met?

Comment: @TylerNisshokuKnowlden Yes, that is correct.  I'll write a quick answer so you can close this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Thomas noted, the entire test needs to also be enclosed in braces.  You currently have:

```
if (attackReady) || (currentExp >= NeededExp) {...}
```

and what you want is either:

```
if ( (attackReady) || (currentExp >= NeededExp) ) {...}
```

or more simply:

```
if (attackReady || currentExp >= NeededExp) {...}
```

One more thing:

From your description, it might be the case that you want both tests to be true to execute that block of code.  If that is the case you want to use an *AND* with `&&` rather than the `||` *OR* test.  `OR` is true if either the left or the right hand side is true.

Comment: Yeah I changed it now so that it's all inside one set of parentheses and changed it to the && instead of || and everything started working properly now. Thanks for the assistance.